# Google Charts External Javascript Issue

Tags: javascript, charts, external

My Problem is, when i put js code of any google chart in an external javascript file. it start loading page and dosen't display any thing. in case of inline javascripts its working fine.

following is my HTML code "google barchart.html"

```
 <html>
     <head>
       <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />    
       <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
       <script type="text/javascript"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <input type="button" id="btn" value="Show Graph" />
      <div id="chart_div" style="width: 441px; height: 300px;"></div>
    </body>
 </html>
```

and this is my js file "test.js"

```
 $(document).ready(function()  {    $('#btn').click(function()      {   //alert("hi");
       google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
          ['', 'Your Restaurant', 'Other Restaurants'],
          ['Question1',  5, 4],
          ['Question2',  4, 5],
          ['Question3',  3, 2],
          ['Question4',  5, 1]
        ]);

        var options = {
          //title: 'Company Performance',
          hAxis: {title: 'Questions', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
          vAxis: {title: '1 = POOR, 5 = EXCELLENT', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}, maxValue:'5', minValue:'1'},
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        chart.draw(data, options);
      }     }); });
```

*NOTE: it also working fine in external js when this piece of code is not in any js function. but i want to use this in Javascript function.

Thnx in advance.

Moaz

Answer (score 6):

I fixed up your code into 2 working solutions you may use (tested working with IE, Chrome and Mozilla).

1. JavaScript loads with index page
2. JavaScript loads after button click

.

---

**Solution 1: JavaScript loads with index page**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</head>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Show Graph">
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 441px; height: 300px;"></div>
</html>
```

test.js

```
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

$(document).ready(function() {    
$("#btn").click(function() {
$("#chart_div").load("", function(){
var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ['', 'Your Restaurant', 'Other Restaurants'],
           ['Question1',  5, 4],
           ['Question2',  4, 5],
           ['Question3',  3, 2],
           ['Question4',  5, 1]
           ]);

var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    hAxis: {title: 'Questions', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
    vAxis: {title: '1 = POOR, 5 = EXCELLENT', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}, maxValue:'5', minValue:'1'},
    tooltip: {trigger: 'hover'}};

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options);
});
});
});
```

---

**Solution 2: JavaScript loads after button click**

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages':['corechart']});

function loadjsfile(filename, filetype) 
     {
  var fileref=document.createElement('script')
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
  document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref)
     }
</script>
</head>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Show Graph" onclick="loadjsfile('test2.js','js')">
<div id="chart_div" style="width: 441px; height: 300px;"></div>
</html>
```

test2.js

```
$("#chart_div").load("",function(){
var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
           ['', 'Your Restaurant', 'Other Restaurants'],
           ['Question1',  5, 4],
           ['Question2',  4, 5],
           ['Question3',  3, 2],
           ['Question4',  5, 1]
           ]);

var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    hAxis: {title: 'Questions', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}},
    vAxis: {title: '1 = POOR, 5 = EXCELLENT', titleTextStyle: {color: '#FF0000'}, maxValue:'5', minValue:'1'},
    tooltip:{trigger: 'hover'}};

var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
chart.draw(data, options)
});
```

Comment: you saved my day @Mike, this is the solution I've been looking for. By the way, before my chart is loaded I can see that my button has been duplicated on the place `<div>` but vanishes after the chart has taken its place. Any ideas my is that happening?

Comment: This helped me! Thanks!